# Flutter Firebase signInWithCustomToken with an existing authentication system's user id?

Tags: laravel, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a Laravel application with it's own user authentication system. I am using firebase only for real-time chat and push notifications.

In order to store chat conversations in firestore, I can directly just write/read data without any auth system. however I need to protect the data with read/write rules to only allow authenticated users.

But I don't want to login the user with email and password again, instead I want to use the `signInWithCustomToken` function. As per the docs, It says I can pass my own customtoken which was created from the laravel application when signing the user in.

Now My question is, I do not want to use the token generated by the laravel application instead I want to use the user's id from the laravel application's database

Laravel application users table:

```
users table:
id | name | email | password | age
1  | mike | mike@example.com | hashedpass | 40
```

in Firebase `signInWithCustomToken` can I pass the user's id like this as the `uid` ?

```
const auth = getAuth();
const token = 1; ------------------------->user id from laravel

signInWithCustomToken(auth, token)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });
```

Is this a good practice? so I can match the user in firebase with the uid and my database's user_id?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `signInWithCustomToken` to sign a user, you will have to *always* mint a custom token for that user. You can't switch from `signInWithEmailAndPassword` to `signInWithCustomToken` for the same user account.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I was a bit confused with the whole`signInWithCustomToken` approach. I was following this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens and now have a better idea. one issue is that I am using php/Laravel for my application and is there no way to generate a customToken without using google service accounts?

Comment: I'm not sure what other way you're looking for to generate a custom token, but any way will require some form of credentials that show that you are authorized to generate tokens for the Firebase project. Otherwise anyone with access to your project's configuration data could generate any auth token they want, which would be a big security leak.